# Crear cron en iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, crontab

Estoy tratando de hacer un cron que se ejecute cada X tiempo en el sistema iOS para que envíe unos datos al servidor.

He leído que no hay ninguna forma de acceder a un cron en un dispositivo que no tenga jailbreak. Investigando un poco he encontrado que lo más cercano a un cron que se puede hacer es utilizar `UILocalNotification` o `Background Fetch` en iOS 7, aunque con estos métodos estas a merced del sistema.

Me he decidido por intentar la opción de Background Fetch y he seguido esta [guía](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/).

El **problema** que estoy teniendo es que parece que no entra a este método y no se lance nunca ni con la App abienta ni en segundo plano.

### Lo que he probado

He activado Los Background Modes de la app seleccionando la opción Background Fetch como se ve en la siguiente foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo en el AppDelegate es el siguiente:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
     NSDate *fetchStart = [NSDate date];
     NSLog(@"Background Fetch: performFetchWithCompletionHandler");

     Utilidades *util = [[Utilidades alloc]init];
     BOOL conexion = [util testInternetConnection];

     //Se comprueba si hay conexión a Internet
     if (conexion) {
         //Envio la información al servidor
         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

     } else {
         NSLog(@"Sin conexión. No se realiza nada");
         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
     }

     NSDate *fetchEnd = [NSDate date];
     NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = [fetchEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:fetchStart];
     NSLog(@"Background Fetch Duration: %f seconds", timeElapsed);
}
```

> ¿Alguien conoce la forma de hacer que se ejecute cada X intervalo
>   independientemente de si está la aplicación en marcha o no? ¿En qué
>   puedo estar fallando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, viendo un par de ejemplos en algunos buscadores, creo que la unica manera de conseguir lo que tu quieres es justamente con `Background Fetch`

En una parte del tutorial que seguiste, te dicen que tienes que definir `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` que es basicamente para definir la frecuencia con el Fetch va a estar trabajando, en el caso particular de ese ejemplo utilizan `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` que es un valor pre-definido.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

    return YES;
}
```

Luego definir la funcion que se encargara logicamente de actualizar los datos que necesitas mantener que es la que dejas en tu pregunta `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`

Lo que tu deberias tener en esta funcion es :

```
-(void) application: (UIApplication * ) application performFetchWithCompletionHandler: (void( ^ )(UIBackgroundFetchResult)) completionHandler {

    NSDate *fetchStart = [NSDate date];

    ViewController * viewController = (ViewController * ) self.window.rootViewController;

    [viewController fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler: ^ (UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {
        completionHandler(result);
        NSDate *fetchEnd = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = [fetchEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:fetchStart];
        NSLog(@"Background Fetch Duration: %f seconds", timeElapsed);
    }];
}
```

Y en tu `ViewController.m` definir `fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler` que debe tener la lógica que se encarga de obtener los datos tal como esta en el tutorial.

Sin olvidarte que para probar esto debes seguir algunos pasos:
1)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias @sioesi, acabo de revisar y me faltaba ` [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];` se me pasó por alto!!

Comment: @Joacer saludos!! y si tienes algun repositorio o codigo objective-c para compartir quedo atento!! para ver esas ideas :D (En la pregunta del Cron en Android, desde ese intercambio de ideas que tuvimos utilizo tu solución

Comment: Vale! Esto era para el trabajo, que estoy aprendiendo ahora Objective-C